# Flutter VS Code copy folded code. Not copied, only the first line

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

VS Code version 1.53.2 (Windows10). If you collapse the widget code in flutter and copy this line, then only it will be inserted, the rest of the code will not be there. This is very inconvenient, we all know how long the widget code can be and it is very tedious to select it line by line. This works by default in Android Studio, but not in VS Code.

I tried to set in the settings instead of `auto` -> `indentation` in `User` and `Workspace`. This does not work for `Flutter` syntax.

```
"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the closed vscode bug https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58209,

> You have to make a selection that covers the end of the folded range as well.

Untested, but it seems logical.

Comment: Thank you, I saw this ticket and thought there were changes in two years, but no. If the collapsing code has a second line, then copying will work. But the problem is that I don't have a second line, the code always collapses into exactly one line.

Comment: you've tried selecting starting to the left of the folded line, straight down to the beginning of the next line?  I know it looks weird, but that's a line selection that includes all the hidden stuff at the end.  (EDIT: yes, just confirmed that worked in my VSC.)